# exposing TCP traffic with nginx ingress controller

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, rtmp, nginx-ingress

Currently I am testing on Windows using Docker Desktop with Kubernetes feature on.

I want to stream `RTMP` data over TCP through the Ingress Controller.

I followed the NGINX controller installation guide https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/ and I tried to configure the TCP like https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

Please note `- --tcp-services-configmap=rtmp/tcp-services`

If I push data through port 1936 the connection cannot be established. If I try with 1935 it works. I would like to have the Ingress controller route the traffic to my service and get rid of the `LoadBalancer` since it doesn't really make sense to have one balancer after another.

With the following configuration I was expecting that sending data to 1936 would work.

Am I missing something?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: restreamer1-service
  namespace: rtmp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: restreamer1-service
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1935
      targetPort: 1935
      name: rtml-com
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      name: http-com
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: rtmp
data:
  1936: "rtmp/restreamer1-service:1935"
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0@sha256:3dd0fac48073beaca2d67a78c746c7593f9c575168a17139a9955a82c63c4b9a
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --tcp-services-configmap=rtmp/tcp-services
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
```

Comment: Can you try sending your request directly to `node-ip:1936`? Also, is this running on a cloud provider? Describe your infrastructure, please.

Comment: It is a local single node cluster on my machine created with Docker Desktop with Kubernetes.

Comment: Port 1936 is not even defined in your deployment not in the service. How does it work?

Comment: I agree with Manuel Polacek, port `1936` should be defined in your configuration.
Can you update your configuration ?

Comment: Can you please share the ingress-nginx-controller Pod Log ?

Also can you exec into the ingress-nginx-controller Pod and check if netstat is showing that it is listening on Port 1936 ?

Comment: Also, please understand that ingress-nginx-controller Pod should be listening on Port 1936 inside its own Network Namespace. It will not be listening on Port 1936 of your Windows Machine since you have not specified hostNetwork = true in your ingress-nginx deployment spec. Please see Link https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#via-the-host-network if you want your ingress-nginx pod to start listening on Port 1936 of your Windows Machine.

What IP are you using to push data through Port 1936 and what IP are you using to push data through Port 1935 ?